# Is it viable to build a Web Dashboard in Clojure?

Tags: web, clojure, dashboard

I am planning to build a web dashboard where I can analyze the financial records from a company through graphics, tables, ...

I already have the software, so the dashboard will only read the data, and not manipulate it.

It will be something like this, but simpler. Containing reports, graphics, options to select dates, intervals, etc.
[image: Gentella]

But I am thinking, is it viable to use Clojure? And jQuery, CSS, HTML also.

Currently I work with the Luminus Web Framework for Clojure, but I am wondering if it is worth to do this in Clojure or if there are other languages that are better to do it.

Of course I am familiar with the language already, so it is a pro. But I am also open to suggestions.

Comment: You know about [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript), correct?

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but only the basics. Never really used it. Is Hoplon a good framework for this purpose?

Comment: I haven't used Hoplon, so I don't know. I'd definitely recommend looking into ClojureScript, though.

Comment: I will, for sure, thanks. And is it a good idea to use a framework? If so, which one do you recommend?

Comment: I'm not really qualified to answer that question, sorry. The only sure thing is that ClojureScript is the way to go if you want to write a web app with Clojure.

Answer (score 5):

It is not that hard at all! In fact, there exist great libraries which solve all the challenges involved in building a dashboard - scheduling, caching, transferring data to the client, visualization(and auto reloading).

We are working on a framework for building realtime Clojure dashboard. Have a look at https://github.com/multunus/dashboard-clj. We have used the following libraries:

- [Immutant's scheduler](http://immutant.org/tutorials/scheduling/) for scheduling
- [Core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) to simplify data flow on the backend
- [Sente](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente) for websocket communication
- [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame) for client side state and view management
- Stuart Sierra's [component library](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) for managing stateful components

In order to create beautiful visualizations you may take a look at d3 or highcharts. [CLJSJS](http://cljsjs.github.io/) and [Reagent cookbook](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-cookbook) will gives a good overview of how to use these js libraries(and many many more).

Answer (score 4):

Clojure is an absolutely fantastic tool for building a web dashboard. The other answers here do a pretty good job of laying out the landscape as far as basic web technologies. On this side of things, I'll simply add I'm a big Reagent / Re-frame fan, and would go that route for React wrapper over Om.

As far as data visualizations, you may be interested in checking out Vega-Lite & Vega, which you can use from Clojure or ClojureScript (Reagent) by using a simple but flexible dataviz library I wrote called Oz:

https://github.com/metasoarous/oz

Vega-Lite & Vega are designed based on the ideas of the Grammar of Graphics, which inspired R's popular ggplot2 library. The core idea is that data visualizations should be built according to declarative descriptions of how properties of the data map to aesthetics of the visualization. Vega-Lite & Vega however take things one step further in providing a grammar of interaction, which allows for the construction of interactive data visualizations and sophisticated explorer views. Moreover, it ups the ante on the declarative nature of the GG in that Vega-Lite and Vega specifications are described as pure data (JSON), making it very in line with the data-driven philosophy of the Clojure world, and paving the way for seamless interoperability with other languages and sharing features.

Vega-Lite is more or less the higher lever, day-to-day data science tool, focusing on providing high leverage and automation based on very spartan specifications. It compiles to Vega, which is a somewhat lower level and more powerful, but less automated version of Vega-Lite. Usually starting out with Vega-Lite, and switching to Vega only as needed is sufficient.

For more on Vega & Vega-Lite see: https://vega.github.io.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reasons why it wouldn't be viable to build a web dashboard in Clojurescript.

I suggest that you look into a library call [reagent](http://holmsand.github.io/reagent/), which provides a minimalistic interface between react and clojurescript, so theoretically everything you can do with react should be possible in clojurescript/reagent (with the added benefit that it will be faster than React). You probably might be interested in [reframe](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame) which is a framework for building single page applications.

React has been proven as a robust tool to build powerful UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything you can do in JavaScript using [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript) (just as you can do everything you do in Java using Clojure). So as others have commented, I would definitely recommend ClojureScript, especially since you know Clojure already. You may find out that you do not need jQuery etc.

The common choice to generate html is to use [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) via a wrapper library like:

- [reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent)
- [Om](https://github.com/omcljs/om)

Both can generate HTML.

[Reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent) (and maybe [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame)) are the easiest ones to get started. Especially since there are components libraries like [soda-ash](https://github.com/gadfly361/soda-ash), and a hiccup-like syntax.

[Om](https://github.com/omcljs/om) (by the creator of ClojureScript), and maybe [untangled](http://untangled-web.github.io/untangled/) are also a good choice, especially if you need to manage complex data. You can get a hiccup-like syntax via [sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono).
Dashboards have been built using it (see the [circleCI](https://circleci.com) [dashboard](https://github.com/circleci/frontend) as a real-life dashboard example). This is the one I use personally.

[Hoplon](https://hoplon.io/) is also an interesting choice, as you mentioned.

Also have a look at cljsjs for [pre-packaged js libraries](http://cljsjs.github.io/).

As for the CSS, this is an orthogonal concern but yes of course you can use it (or even less and sass, there are Clojure wrappers for it). You can even generate CSS from Clojure code with [garden](https://github.com/noprompt/garden),

You can find an example project using [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) (by the same authors as hoplon), sass, reagent called [saapas](https://github.com/Deraen/saapas), but there are many more in the wild.

As you see there are many viable options in ClojureScript to build a dashboard. I am myself building one and settled on [Om.next](https://github.com/omcljs/om), partly because I was using React.js before.